# Returning date as json

Tags: json, node.js, express

Using express I'm logging & sending an output object containing dates as json:

```
console.log(outputModel);
res.jsonp({output: outputModel});
```

On the console I can see the correct date `Tue Mar 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)` but in my browser or postman I get that date as `2015-03-30T22:00:00.000Z`.

How can I fix that?

Comment: On your browser can you you run new Date("2015-03-30T22:00:00.000Z")? What are you trying to do with this data?

Comment: I just receive this data as a json.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this data?

Comment: Can you do this on the server:

var date = new Date();

res.jsonp({output: date.toString()});

Comment: Yes, I can. And yes, this "solves" the problem. But I don't want to return my date as a string, but as a date object. Or is that not possible with JSON?

Comment: It is not possible with JSON. JSON escapes all values with double quotes.

Comment: Maybe this article helps you understand: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jan/06/JavaScript-JSON-Date-Parsing-and-real-Dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For format time i recommend you use `Moment`, for example you can send date in unix time and format how you like on client.

```
var receivedUnixTime = 1425554628;
var date = moment(receivedUnixTime).format("Here write format would you like");
```

For moar information http://momentjs.com/docs/;